# Sorting arrays with nonstandard lengths separated by a delimiter

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting

So, I have an array like this `my @array= ( '1/22', '1/3', '1/15', '1/24', '2/1', '3/47' );`
That when sorted should appear as 1/3, 1/15, 1/22, 1/24, 2/1, 3/47.  However, from what I have researched in perl my attempts at either a Schwartzian Transform or the sort command result in an issue where 1/22 would go before 1/3.

This does not make any sense to me as the join command would result in 13, (if I understand correctly) which should sort before 122.

The specific line I am using is `@array= sort { join('', (split '/', $a)[0,1]) cmp join('', (split '/', $b)[0,1]) }  @array`

What exactly do I need to do differently?  I think this case should also fail for things like 2/4 for similar reasons.

Comment: Losing the slash means that `12/3` and `1/23` will appear together.  You need to split into two numbers, and sort by comparing the first number of each pair, and in case of a tie by comparing the second number of each pair.

Comment: Isn't it a rather bad idea to post a question about how to sort something and not say by what rule you want it sorted?

Comment: Sorry for a lack of specification.  I would want ascending order like with my output example.

Comment: Ascending order is not a sorting rule. Numerical ascending order would be a sorting rule, but in your case, you do not want ascending numerical order, since `1/3` is larger than `1/15`.

Comment: So what would be the appropriate rule name? Ascending numerical order by first number then second?

Comment: @Anon29 That would be sufficient, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sort { 
    my @a = split('/', $a); 
    my @b = split('/', $b); 
    $a[0] <=> $b[0] or 
    $a[1] <=> $b[1]; } @list
```

Comment: So, other than the minor syntax errors, this also has issues. The sorting of the first half seems to be overridden by the second half (output like 1/8 2/30 2/38 1/48 1/46)

Comment: @Anon29 Oesor's code has no syntax errors at all, and produces correct output. The second comparison `$a[1] <=> $b[1]` is only performed when the first comparison returns zero (i.e. the first part of the elements are equal to each other).

Comment: @Anon29 No, you did something wrong if you got that. The correct output is `1/8 1/46 1/48 2/30 2/38`.

Comment: The older revision had a rogue ' after the $a, however I changed something else while correcting it that resulted in my incorrect output.  This does indeed work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Sort::Naturally](http://p3rl.org/Sort%3a%3aNaturally) is the easiest way to do this:

```
@array = Sort::Naturally::nsort(@array);
```

Though to accomplish what I think you were intending with your join, you could do:

```
sprintf('%02d%02d', (split '/', $a)[0,1]) cmp sprintf('%02d%02d', (split '/', $b)[0,1])
```

(increase the widths of 2 if needed).